Does the standard HTML files input element include or exclude "Apple double" image files?
Can't find a clear answer to this anywhere and... I'm developing on Windows so I can't test it.
This part of the website uses a standard HTML multiple files input element like so:
      <input type="file" id="image-files-input" name="imageFiles[]" multiple>

If the user navigated to a folder, and did a Ctrl + A to select all images, or just manually selected a group of images, would the hidden Apple double files get included as well? Or does this input element exclude them by default?
I've had past workflows where they somehow got included in parts of the code which caused frustration and bugs.

AppleDouble files aren't a standard, they're a tool that Apple (and many macOS tools) use to preserve complex filesystem metadata in places where they aren't natively supported (e.g. when copying Mac files to an SMB server, archiving them in something like zip or tar formats, etc). Note that they don't actually exist on Apple filesystems (unless something's gone wrong); the complex metadata is stored directly in the filesystem. Normally, AppleDouble files only exist in places that don't know what they are, and will just treat them as ordinary (maybe invisible) files.
